# Formatting two numbers in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, string-formatting

I am coping with the formatting of numbers. I assumed that the `.format` allows to use multiple arguments:

```
a = 1.11111111111
b = 0.9
s = '({0:.2f}, {0:.2f})'.format(a, b)
print(s)
```

Returns:

```
'(1.11, 1.11)'
```

Instead of:

```
'(1.11, 0.90)'
```

On the other hand, this works fine:

```
'({}, {})'.format(a, b)
```

Returns:

```
'(1.11111111111111, 0.9)'
```

Any idea where is the problem?

Comment: Use `s = '({0:.2f}, {1:.2f})'.format(a, b)`, else the `a` value is used since you explicitly indicated to use `a` value the second time.

Comment: As @WiktorStribiżew suggest, you have a wrong identifier for your formatting. The number in front of the colon `:` is the index of the argument of the format function to put in.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You used for both of the the parameters the value a (0), you should call in the second param to value b (1).

the value before the `:` is for giving placeholders an explicit positional index.

This allows for re-arranging the order of display without changing the arguments.

Change

```
s = '({0:.2f}, {0:.2f})'.format(a, b)
```

To:

```
s = '({0:.2f}, {1:.2f})'.format(a, b)
```

Answer (score 7):

Values before the `:` character specify either a field name or a conversion; by using `0` in both cases you're essentially telling `.format`, via the element index, to use `a` in both cases.

In your second case, `'({}, {})'.format(a, b)`, by *not* specifying a position, `.format` replaces each empty pair of `{}` with the elements supplied in increasing order of position.

A simple replacement, as suggested, is to use `1` to indicate that you want to use `b` instead of `a`. Alternatively, simply omit them:

```
s = '({:.2f}, {:.2f})'.format(a, b)
```

to get a similar effect.

---

You should skim through the [Syntax for the format strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) to get an idea of the rules used when formatting.